# MySQL Creating temporary table syntax error

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I am getting a syntax error when I run a MySQL statement.

I know backticks can be added to the tablename to make it work but was wondering why it happens in the first place.

```
Create temporary table 6514202534e1b20f0d6331 (user_id INT (10)) ENGINE=HEAP;
```

If I put this in Mysql Query Browser it treats the table name as two seperate words - `6514202534e1` and `b20f0d6331`.

The table name is generated dynamically and I haven't had a problem with this before, so I was wondering why it stopped working all of a sudden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because the server (mysql) understands it in this case as 6514202534*e^1 INT.

Using the ` character:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `6514202534e1b20f0d6331` (user_id INT (10)) ENGINE=HEAP;
```

In this way the MySQL Server understands (explicitly) that the whole phrase is database, table or field not a value or function, etc.

For example `order` is legal while just order will rise an error for invalid order clause.

Comment: Read his question carefully: "I know backticks can be added to the tablename to make it work but was wondering why it happens in the first place."

Comment: Thanks for the answer, 'e1' was indeed the problem. The error can be fixed by using backticks or starting the table name with a letter rather than a number.